# How to add transitions to a drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, css-transitions

I have a drop-down menu that makes text appear when clicked. However, when I add transitions to it, nothing happens. It still just shows up without sliding down. I want the transition to show the text gradually from top to bottom as it appears.

This is the CSS:

```
.drop-down {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

`.menu` is the class name for the button clicked that shows this `.drop-down` text.

I don't know if I used the `transition` properly.

Should I have used JavaScript instead? And if not what do I need to change?

JavaScript Code:

```
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu')
const menuContent = document.querySelector('.drop-down')

menu.addEventListener('click', menuClick, false);
menuContent.style.display = 'none'

function menuClick() {
    menuContent.classList.toggle('show');
    if (menuContent.style.display == 'none') {
        menuContent.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        menuContent.style.display = 'none'
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes share your JavaScript to be able to help you

Comment: Notice, that if you using `display` property to hide the text. The `transition` property can't work. Try any trick to show/hide the text like `opacity` property.

Comment: Oh that does make sense. I did use `display` in my JavaScript

Comment: @Philo I added the JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without javascript.

```html
.drop-down {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
  .menu:hover .drop-down{
   opacity:1;
   visibility:visible;
}
```